# input type text data not being inserted in the sql DB

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am trying to make a form and insert those values in my DB. What I was trying to do here is that, getting the values of dropdown menu into the disabled text field above them, and insert those values into my Db. Problem is that: Any of the dropdown/ disabled text field's value is not being inserted into my DB, they are just Blank. I want them to be inserted.

Below is my HTML code.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Trademark Filing Application</title>

<link rel="icon" href="\images\trademark_icon.png" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">


</head>
<body>


<h2 ><img src="images/hero_logo.png" class="herologo" ><span class="form-title">Trademark Filing Application</span></h2><br>

<div>
<p style="padding-left:20px"><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>

  <form action="insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <!-- Department  -->

    <b>Select Department:</b><span class="error"> *</span>
    <select id="dept" name="department" required>
    <option value="">Please Select...</option>
      <option value="CEO Office">CEO Office</option>
      <option value="Global">Global</option>
      <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
      <option value="Parts">Parts</option>

    </select>
    <br><br><br>


    <!-- Class  -->

    <b>Select Class:</b><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>
    <input type="radio" id="wordradio" name="classs" value="Word" required>Word
    <input type="radio" id="deviceradio" name="classs" value="Device" style="margin-left:20px">Device
    <input type="radio" id="logoradio" name="classs" value="Logo" style="margin-left:20px">Logo
    <input type="radio" id="soundradio" name="classs" value="Sound" style="margin-left:20px">Sound
    <input type="radio" id="taglineradio" name="classs" value="Tagline" style="margin-left:20px">Tagline
    <br><br><br>


    <!-- Preferences  -->


    <b>Enter Preference(s):</b><br>
    1. <input type="text" id="pref1" name="preference1" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 1" required>
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn1" name="image" multiple="" required>
    <span class="error">*</span>
    <br>

    2. <input type="text" id="pref2" name="preference2" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 2">
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn2" name="preferTwo[]" multiple="" >

    <br>
    3. <input type="text" id="pref3" name="preference3" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 3">
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn3" name="preferThree[]" multiple="" >

    <br>
    4. <input type="text" id="pref4" name="preference4" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 4">
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn4" name="preferFour[]" multiple="" >

    <br>
    5. <input type="text" id="pref5" name="preference5" style="width:30%" placeholder="Preference 5">
    <input type="file" id="prefbtn5" name="preferFive[]" multiple="" >

    <br><br><br>


    <!-- Goods and Services  -->


    <b>Enter The Types of Goods & Services :</b><span class="error"> *</span>
    <br>
    <input type="text" id="goodss" name="goodsnservice" placeholder="Select the type of Goods and Services" required>

    <br><br><br>


    <!-- Mark in Use?  -->

   <b>Is Mark In Use?</b><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>
    <input type="radio" id="marky" name="mark" value="yes" onclick="disableNo()" required>Yes


    <!-- Mark in Use?: YES  -->


    <div id="markyes" class="show-hide" style="background-color:white;width:600px ;margin-left:40px; border:1px solid black; border-radius:5px"><br>
    <b>When Did You Use It?</b>
    <input type="date" name="yeswhen" style="margin-left:10px" id="markyesdate" required><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>

    <b>Where Did You Use It?</b><span class="error"> *</span><br>

    <input type="text" style="height:10px;width:50%" id="selected_yes" name="yes_country_values" disabled /> <br/>
    <select name="yescountry" id="yescountry" style="width:40%" multiple required>
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
        <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
        <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select><br><br>

            <b>Proof Of First Use:</b><span class="error"> *</span><br>
    <input type="file" id="markyesproof" name="yesProof[]" value="Upload proof" multiple="" required>
    </div><br>


            <!-- Mark in Use?: NO  -->


    <input type="radio" name="mark" value="no" onclick="disableYes()" >No<br>
    <div id="markno" class="show-hide" style="background-color:white;width:600px ;margin-left:40px; border:1px solid black; border-radius:5px"><br>
    <b>When Are You Expected To Use It?</b>
    <input type="date" name="nowhen" style="margin-left:10px" id="marknodate" required><span class="error"> *</span><br><br>

    <b>Where will You Use It?</b><span class="error"> *</span><br>

    <input type="text" style="height:10px;width:50%" id="selected_no" name="no_country_values" disabled /><br/>

        <select name="marknocountry" id="nocountry" style="width:40%" multiple required>
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Zaire">Zaire</option>
        <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
        <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
        </select><br/><br/>


    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#yescountry').on('change', function() {
    $('#selected_yes').val($(this).val());
  });

  $('#nocountry').on('change', function() {
    $('#selected_no').val($(this).val());
  });

  $('#appliedcountry').on('change', function() {
    $('#selected_applied').val($(this).val());
  });

});
</script>

<script>
function disableNo() {
    document.getElementById("nocountry").required = false;
    document.getElementById("marknodate").required = false;      
}

function disableYes() {
    document.getElementById("yescountry").required = false;
    document.getElementById("markyesdate").required = false;
    document.getElementById("markyesproof").required = false;      
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is my Php code:

```
    <?php

    include'upload.php';
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','abcdef','trademark');

if(!$con) { 
    echo "Not Connected To Server";
} else {

    $_POST = array_map(function($value) {
        return empty($value) ? "NULL" : $value;
    }, $_POST);

    $Department =           !empty($_POST['department']) ? $_POST['department'] : "";
    $Classs =               !empty($_POST['classs']) ? $_POST['classs'] : "";
    $Preference1 =          !empty($_POST['preference1']) ? $_POST['preference1'] : "";
    $Preference2 =          !empty($_POST['preference2']) ? $_POST['preference2'] : "";
    $Preference3 =          !empty($_POST['preference3']) ? $_POST['preference3'] : "";
    $Preference4 =          !empty($_POST['preference4']) ? $_POST['preference4'] : "";
    $Preference5 =          !empty($_POST['preference5']) ? $_POST['preference5'] : "";
    $Goods =                !empty($_POST['goodsnservice']) ? $_POST['goodsnservice'] : "";
    $Mark =                 !empty($_POST['mark']) ? $_POST['mark'] : "";
    $MarkYesWhen =          !empty($_POST['yeswhen']) ? $_POST['yeswhen'] : "";
    $MarkYesCountry =       !empty($_POST['yes_country_values']) ? $_POST['yes_country_values'] : "";
    $MarkNoWhen =           !empty($_POST['nowhen']) ? $_POST['nowhen'] : "";
    $MarkNoCountry =        !empty($_POST['no_country_values']) ? $_POST['no_country_values'] : "";
    $MarkAppliedCountry =   !empty($_POST['applied_selected_values']) ? $_POST['applied_selected_values'] : "";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO requestor (
        Department,
        Class,
        Preference_One,
        Preference_Two,
        Preference_Three,
        Preference_Four,
        Preference_Five,
        Goods_Services,
        Mark_In_Use,
        Mark_Yes_When,
        Mark_Yes_Country,
        Mark_No_When,
        Mark_No_Country,
        Mark_Applied_Country,
        Flag
    ) VALUES(
        '$Department',
        '$Classs',
        '$Preference1',
        '$Preference2',
        '$Preference3',
        '$Preference4',
        '$Preference5',
        '$Goods',
        '$Mark',
        '$MarkYesWhen',
        '$MarkYesCountry',
        '$MarkNoWhen',
        '$MarkNoCountry',
        '$MarkAppliedCountry',
        0
    )";

    $r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    header("refresh:0 ; url=success.php");

    }



    ?>​
```

Comment: use `readonly` instead of `disabled`.

Comment: Try using `print_r($_POST); die;` and check all the values that you are getting along with which fields are empty.

It'll also help you to understand that which values aren't coming from the form.

Comment: Thank you, it's working now. :)  . If you can, then please upvote the question, so that I can gain more reputation points and can upvote answers. Else, someday I'll get blocked from asking any further question. thanks again @TarangP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get disabled fields value in Post request. Instead of disabled you can use hidden.

Change it in your html and it should work.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion also worked. If you can, then please upvote the question, so that I can gain more reputation points and can upvote answers. Else, someday I'll get blocked from asking any further question. thanks again